# Google sheets API parameters

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have an appScript API code that returns JSON data from google sheets I want to search data depending on sent request parameter for example if sent parameter is greater than 90000 then search data using Mobile  field and if it is less than 90000 then search data using PatCode field.

## code is attached and also snapshot of data header

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
var rng = ss.getDataRange()
var data = rng.getValues()
var headings = data[0]

/* Take a product ID as input and return the
 *  row corresponding to that product ID.*/

function patientQuery(q)
{

  
 let dataList = [];
 for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++)
   {
     if (q === data[i][3])
     {
       dataList.push(data[i]); // This should return data[i] instead of the first row which is the header
     }
   }

  return dataList; // Return a list of products instead
}

/* Take a spreadsheet (product) row and turn it into an object
 with spreadsheet headings as object keys.*/


function formatProduct(rowData){
 var product = {}
 for (var i = 0; i < headings.length; i++){
   product[headings[i].toString()] = rowData[i]
 }
 return product
}


function doGet(request) {
 // Check for a valid request URI

   if (request.parameter.q !== undefined){
     let Mobile = request.parameters.q
   
     // The object to be returned as JSON
     let response = {
       patients : []
     }
    
     // Fill the products array with requested products
     for (var i = 0; i < Mobile.length; i++){  
     /** CHANGES - START*/
       patientQuery(Mobile[i]).forEach((sheetData, index) => { // Iterate trough the items list
         let product = formatProduct(sheetData)
         product.Serial = index + 1
         response.patients.push(product)
       })
       
     /** CHANGES - END*/
     }
    
     if (response.patients.length > 0){
       return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(response));
     } else {
       //return ContentService.createTextOutput('Invalid Request. Product ID(s) not found.');
       return ContentService.createTextOutput('No recodrs found.');
     }     
   } else {
           return ContentService.createTextOutput('Invalid Request. Use at least one valid "Mobile number" 
parameter.');
   }

}
```

[image: data]

Comment: Could you let us know what part of this code does not behave the way you want? Does some of it work? Does it return anything? Or is it the searching the spreadsheet you need help with? You have not asked any questions :)

Comment: It's working but get result of searching one field only i want to search using 2 parameters instead of one. I explained that and mentioned : (if sent parameter is greater than 90000 then search data using Mobile field and if it is less than 90000 then search data using PatCode field.)

Comment: It's your responsibility to create a [mcve] which is normally something less than the actual code that produces the same result.  Performing this solution normally results in one of two outcome.  First in the process of creating you often find the solution on your own and if not then we have something that is easier to debug.  If your unwilling to do that work then you're not as likely to get our help

Comment: According to what you have explained, request parameter `q` should just be a number, that is either under 90k or over. However, in your code you assign `let Mobile = request.parameters.q;`  so `Mobile` should be a number, right? However then you call `Mobile.length` in your `for` loop. Which is just confusing. I think you need to try and simplify your question and provide some sample data and requests. Read the minimal reproducible example article linked by Cooper.